# Does Karate Champ ever end?

Tags: karate-champ

I'm in a nostalgic mood today, when I found an old arcade machine of Karate Champ:

[image]

After beating everyone to the 8th level and losing, I was thinking: Does this game ever end? Or this is a game like River Raid that never ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that people are [still setting high scores](http://replay.marpirc.net/r/kchamp) on this game (exceeding a million points!), I don't believe it ever ends.  You'll just keep facing the master over and over again until you fail.

Comment: Wow, never thought people were still setting high scores on this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that Karate Champ VS never ends. I got to 10th DAN and kept fighting figher after fighter. The backgrounds changed but you keep facing a 10th DAN ranked fighter until you either lose or the arcade closes!

Great game, an all time favourite of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Level 12 is the Final Dojo. I have never beaten level 12. When you beat Level 12, you start over at Level 1 again, and the game is much much harder.

Comment: Which version of the game are you referring ? I just went to level 9.